# How to open git project on mac?

Tags: git, github, repository

A client sent me a `.git` file, and says to run the project. I am not sure how to download it. Is it possible to download a project if you have ".git" file available. Please help. This is an iOS project, and I am using Mac.

Comment: Found out that the url, I was downloading from was actually a ".git" url, and had to download the project through SourceTree or something similar by giving url there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trying import your file to [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

It's an IDE, so maybe it's will be easier than using command line in Terminal.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I never did exactly that, but what if you create a folder, put the .git file there, navigate to that folder in terminal and then run `git pull origin master`?

Answer (score 0):

I never saw any `.git` files.

But I know, that git stores the whole information about the repository in  folders with this name. Maybe he send you a folder?

Try to do it the way Andrey Chernukha told you and tell us about the results.